# Extra pins on HD44780 lcd

Tags: lcd, datasheet, pins, hd44780

I am looking at ordering this lcd https://www.sparkfun.com/products/255, however when looking at the picture it seems that there are some extra pins on the right side not described in the hd4470 datasheet.  I was hoping someone could explain their use to me.  Here is the picture [image]

I would assume that the LCD would act normally if I left these pins unconnected, but please correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking in the [datasheet](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/LCD/GDM1602K.pdf) I can see this:

[image]

and

[image]

So they are the same as pins 15 and 16. Leave them not connected and use only pins 15 and 16.

Comment: What about the 4 other pins next to A and K

Comment: @popgalop A and K are 2 pins each, so only 2 pins left. They're probably the same A and K. Use a continuity tester or ohmeter to get an idea. Anyway, leaving them not connected wouldn't do any harm.

Answer (score 1):

The HD44780 protocol only requires a maximum of 14 pins, usually found either along the long edge in a single row or on one of the short edges in a double row. There may be 16 instead, in which case the extra 2 are for the LED backlight. No other connections to the module should be required.